# php: can I create and call function inside a class method?

Tags: php, class, function

is it possible to create function inside a class method and how do I call it ?

i.e.

```
class Foo
{
    function bar($attr)
    {
       if($attr == 1)
       {
          return "call function do_something_with_attr($attr)";
       }
       else
       {
          return $attr;
       }

       function do_something_with_attr($atr)
       {
          do something
          ...
          ...
          return $output;
       }
    }
}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Could the same not be accomplished using a normal (perhaps static) class method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can be done, but since functions are defined in the global scope this will result in an error if the method is called twice since the PHP engine will consider the function to be redefined during the second call.

Comment: I am getting error as Ignacio wrote. Zerkms, could you please explain in more details how to solve with function_exists() ? - Thank You.

Comment: The php documentation is a wonderful thing http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php

Comment: @m1k3y02: You shouldn't have to declare global functions within methods. Declare other methods with `protected` or `private` visibility instead, and call them using `$this`. Unless you really really need a global function...

Answer (score 13):

Yes. As of PHP 5.3, You can use [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) for this:

```
class Foo
{
    function bar($attr)
    {
        $do_something_with_attr = function($atr)
        {
            //do something
            //...
            //...
            $output = $atr * 2;
            return $output;
        };

        if ($attr == 1)
        {
            return $do_something_with_attr($attr);
        }
        else
        {
            return $attr;
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use "function_exists" to avoid errors.

```
class Foo
{
    function bar($attr)
    {

       if (!function_exists("do_something_with_attr")){ 
           function do_something_with_attr($atr)
           {
              do something
              ...
              ...
              return $output;
           }
       }

       if($attr == 1)
       {
          return do_something_with_attr($attr);
       }
       else
       {
          return $attr;
       }


    }
}
```